# Is there an open source sports manager project?

Tags: web, open-source

For a long time I've tried to search for an open source manager game, but without any luck. I'm looking for a suitable project for a reference to my own pet project. Features like well designed data model, tournament and fixture generation and understandable match simulation algorithm would be a great bonuses.

I'm especially interested in game projects like [Hattrick](http://hattrick.org/) and SI Games' Football Manager, although it is irrelevant what the particular sport is. The project should be preferably web-based as Hattrick is.

I've crawled through GitHub and SourceForge, but I found only a few sports simulation projects. Projects, which I have found, were either dead or not fulfilling my wishes.

Do you know any open source manager game / fantasy sports game project, which would be available as open source, OR at least any material, which would be useful when building a such project?

Answer (score 5):

[Score OS](http://www.scoreos.org/) came up on the google search. It's open source [(Google code)](http://code.google.com/p/scoreos/).

Answer (score 2):

Bygfoot is a soccer management game

http://bygfoot.sourceforge.net/new/about/

(does not seem to be very actively developped, though ..)